# Mongoose Model.count() does not run callback as documented

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am following almost [the exact example for Model.count()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count) from the Mongoose docs:

```
User.count({ type: 'jungle' }, function (err, count) {
  console.log('I do not ever run');
});
```

This should print 'I do not ever run'. Instead, it returns a Query object - which should not happen, according to the docs, as I am providing a callback. How can I make the callback function run? Is there some circumstances where the callback is not run?

Using mongoose@3.6.17. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you've connected to the database before calling any model functions.  Mongoose will just queue up the `count` query until you connect otherwise.

See [this question of the FAQ](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#model_functions_hanging).

Comment: Thanks! I'd refactored and accidentally killed the .connect() earlier in the code.